# Is Stackdriver region-local?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We're deploying our application in EU, and would like our data, including logs, to be stored inside of EU region only. It's perfectly OK for the data to travel & be stored between the zones within the EU region though.

Is Stackdriver guarantees that the log data remains in the EU, if we run our app within the EU region?

In a similar question from 2018 on Google Groups named "[Are Stackdriver logs region-bound?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-stackdriver-discussion/0GqgwEx9RDM)", there are two seemingly contradictory statements:

> ... Stackdriver's underlying storage replicates logs across **multiple zones in the same region**.

and

> Logs are currently a global service, though **regional storage guarantees are on our roadmap**.

So, is it possible that currently logs will leave EU region and be replicated somewhere outside of EU?

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver logs are, by default, multi regional.  However, if you want a more defined method of storing logs, you can take a look at this solution [1]. This will explain how to export and preserve logs files with different methods of keeping them safe. Also, this article [2] will explain how to manipulate logging with a more detailed method.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-compliance-requirements
[2]https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging

Comment: Also for all services you can take a look in the GCP docs to see if a service is region 
 bound or global. https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/